# Imgur reports image has "wrong format", but what is wrong?

Tags: support, images

There is an older question about how to embed images, but it is out-of-date, the system currently goes right to the Imgur panel. When I try to use this to link to an image on the wiki commons, I get an error about it being the wrong format. The images are JPG or GIF, which strikes me as odd.

I *suspect* the error message is inaccurate, and it is some other problem. But how do I find out what's actually going on?

UPDATE: as requested... this happens all the time, on different images. In this particular case I...

1. clicked the embed image button
2. clicked "link from the web"
3. pasted in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfoil#/media/File:Lift_drag_graph.JPG

And then tried to post it. I also tried two other images from different web sites, but I am not sure which ones, it was some time ago now.

Comment: Can share what you try to upload? If you use a weblink to a wiki commons "image" it might be that you're actually served an html page with an image embedded on it. Works fine in your browser, not so when Imgur tries to grab that same content as they will see *text/html* not *image/png*. But it can be difficult to distinguish upfront, causing the unexpected behavior you see now.

Comment: Ahh, now I see the problem, you have to click through the image to get the right link. So I guess this is a feature request.

Comment: And my original post was correct: the error message is misleading. The problem is not the image's format, it's the pages. That should be made clear. Who do I report this to? Is the form a local one, or one that imgur provides?

Comment: I think it is a bit of both so I'm not sure where this particular check is done.

Comment: Should I post it as a request here?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz We have to clarify where that validation is done in 1st place. Imgur or Stack Exchange.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Indeed, but who will do so?

Comment: Did you tried with a URI without special char, like : ?

Comment: _@MauryMarkowitz_ Well @rene had at least [brought it up](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6980569#6980569) at a place where a lot of SE Devs frequently appear.

Comment: Ok, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 7):

The link you have is just the link to the Wikipedia page of the image, to open the actual image **Right Click → Open Image in New Tab** (or just **Copy Image Address**) and use *that* link.

In your case the actual link is:

[`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Lift_drag_graph.JPG`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Lift_drag_graph.JPG)

Comment: Indeed. And the error message should clearly state this. Something like "the URL you have posted is to a complete web page, not an image". I suspect this happens a lot, a better error would have handy.

Comment: I don't think Imgur recognizes it, it just recognizes it as a *non-image* (or bad format).

Comment: No, I get that, this is now a feature request. The question is where such a thing should be posted.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz It's likely an imgur FR. (We use their system and it just reports back whatever they say)

Comment: Is the form itself on Imgut too? Or is the form local and calling their API? If it's the later, would it be reasonable to filter some problems on this end?

Comment: Idk, see the message when you go to http://stack.imgur.com/ (maybe ask Alan)

Comment: Asked... we'll see what happens, worst case he'll know where to go for the next step.

Comment: sorry i tried this but it no longer worked now.  screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uypKi.png